# Range Loop for Data Clean-up

Tags: excel, for-loop, boolean, conditional-formatting, vba

This seems like it should be simple, but I have been getting error codes all afternoon:
I have data that I am trying to clean up to graph (it's exported from a retaining system that sometime leaves "blank" cells not actually blank).  So, I figured I could run a "IsNumeric" formula to get TRUE/FALSE values, but now I am running into the issue of how to replace the existing non-blanks that appear as blank with a value of my choosing.

All of the data is in column A, and then column B has the TRUE/FALSE formula running:

```
=ISNUMBER(A1) 'from rows 1 to 4378
```

I am hoping to be able to have a macro write to column C something along these lines (at least, this is the best I have come up with, but it is not working):

```
Sub WayEatFresh()

Dim dbsheet As Worksheet

Set dbsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

lr = dbsheet.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To lr

If dbsheet.Range(x,2).Value = True Then
    dbsheet.Range(x,3).Value = dbsheet.Range(x,1).Value
Else dbsheet.Range(x,3).Value = 0
End If

Next x

End Sub
```

I am not sure how to resolve the Run-time error "'1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed".

Any pointers?

---

Editing the original code per the suggestions provided by @nwhaught, I added a few things to the code and it is now working.  Here is the final iteration (any explanation of why this worked over the other version is most welcome!):

```
Sub WayEatFresh()

Dim x As Integer

With ThisWorkbook

For x = 1 To 4378

If Cells(x, 2).Value = True Then
Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value

Else
Cells(x, 3).Value = 0

End If

Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I have a few questions.. 1) What exactly is the desired conclusion of the problem you are trying to solve?  From what I can gather it sounds like you either do _not_ want those blanks to show up in the graph or you want them to appear as 0?  Could you clarify that?  2) May I ask what is the reasoning behind using VBA over a formula for this next column? 3) What is the conditional-formatting tag for?

Comment: Which line gives the error message? Why do you want to do this with a macro, it would be more easier with a formula: `=IF(ISNUMERIC(A1),A1,0)`

Comment: do you actually want to KEEP the blanks? or delete them eventually? If you want to delete the blanks, delete the entire row when your x reaches a blank. (unless there is something else on that row you want to keep of course). With this new blank-less table, you should graph properly.

Comment: @chancea : my reason for wanting VBA is primarily because a formula will generate a formula in the cell (as I am cleaning up the cells to be used in graphing and analysis later).  I need the cells to only contain numbers.  The problem is that when I export the data into excel, the "blanks" are not truly blank.  Somehow in the conversion the blanks end up with a space or some invisible formatting that does not register as truly blank. I want to identify those and then place a real number in them.

Comment: @DavidGM I want to be able to take all the cells that return "FALSE" and input 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Cells` notation within your `Range`.

`Cells` has the form `([RowNumber],[ColNumber])`.

`Range` has the form `([CellAddress],[CellAddress])` or `(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,2))`.

For your code, I'd recommend replacing your `Range`s with `Cells`s.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I have incorporated your suggestions and am now getting another error..."Subscript Out of Range". Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3794203 your loop is likely going too far. Post the code you have edited here, I can help you fix that error.

Comment: Not sure how I got it to work, but it is working now! I will edit my original post to include the changes using the suggestions that  nwhaught made. If you are able to explain how it is now working, that would be awesome because it is almost always trial and error when I work with VBA. Thank you, @David GM

Comment: You are using the correct notation for cells(row, column) now, which is why it works. Your loop starts at 1, and X represents a row throughout since you placed it as the first argument for Cells(row, column). So for [row 1, you have:] If column 2 = true, put the value of column 1 inside column 3. Else, put 0 in column 3. [Next row up: 2] If column 2 = true, put the value of column 1 inside column 3. Else, put 0 in column 3. [Next row..... up to 4378]. That's all, I'm not sure I can explain further.